# Preselecting option in multiselect using val()

Tags: jquery

How do you preselect an option in a multiple select html tag using jquery's val()?

What I mean by this is that say you have a multiselect component and you want some of the values to be preselected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can pass an array of values to the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$("#yourSelect").val(["value1", "value2"]);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/uXEVJ/1/).

Comment: @imparator - Iterate over the set of selected `option` elements and call `.prop("selected", false)` on the ones you want to deselect. Or call `.val()` again and pass in the values you do want selected.

Comment: Blazemonger - that will unselect all values ... I am talking about unselecting specific values

Comment: @james: please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imparator/XPGa8/1/ I have some trouble unselecting. Here is description of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638051/unselecting-values-in-multiselect-using-val-and-prop

Comment: how do I do the same with javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>​
```

jQuery:

```
$("select").val(["volvo", "mercedes"]).prop("selected", true);
```

Here's a fiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/HCm3e/

Comment: You don't need the `prop` call. It doesn't make sense, since it's going to set the `selected` property of the `select` element (not an `option` element).

Comment: @scumah - in your fiddle, the ("selected", false) does not do unselecting. Any idea why that is the case?