# Unselecting values in multiselect using val() and prop

Tags: jquery

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imparator/XPGa8/1/

First, I am selecting the value "Volvo" of the select list:

```
$("select").val('volvo');
```

Later, when I try to unselect it like this:

```
$("select").val('volvo').prop("selected", false);
```

The value volvo still stays selected as you can see from the fiddle.

How can I unselect a value in multiselect using jquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `$("select option[value='volvo']").prop("selected", false);`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XPGa8/3/)**

Also, you should mark an option as selected like this:

```
$("select option[value='volvo']").prop("selected", true);
$("select option[value='audi']").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: What if I wanted to select volvo and audi in one line: $("select option[value='volvo']").prop("selected", true); or unselect them in one line? Do I just separate them with commas?

Comment: @imparator Yes separate using a comma: `$("select option[value='volvo'], select option[value='audi']").prop("selected", true);`

Comment: Another question: I have two multiselect components. Can I use the id of the select together with option `$("#selectid1 option[value='volvo']")`

Comment: @j08691 - The OP has `select` elements with the `multiple` attribute, so it's much easier to set multiple selections with `val`, rather than finding the `option` elements and using `prop`. OPs original question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636743/preselecting-option-in-multiselect-using-val/