# Set selected values in multi select using chosen jquery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I am using a model to populate my multi select drop down, I am using the chosen Jquery helper to change the multi select. But when I want to edit an entry from the db I want to show the selected values from the db. I am struggling to set the selected values, but I can show the option values.

I am using ruby on rails as my frame work

```
<%= f.collection_select :categories,
    Category.all ,:id,:name,
    { include_blank: true},
    { class: 'chosen-select', :multiple=>true, :data => { :placeholder => ' ' }}
    %>
```

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in 'selected' option with current categories, e.g.

```
<%= f.collection_select :categories,
  Category.all ,:id,:name,
  { include_blank: true, selected: @categories.map(&:id)},
  { class: 'chosen-select', :multiple=>true, :data => { :placeholder => ' ' }}
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636743/preselecting-option-in-multiselect-using-val), you should be able to use this:

```
$("#yourSelect").val(["value1", "value2"]);
```

Comment: Cool this is helpful, but i am passing the selected values from the controller, and it seems you need to know the selected values but i need to do this dynamically

Comment: Or we can use like $("#yourSelect").val(arrayName);

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MVC it is really easy.

```
model.MySelectList= new MultiSelectList(itemsToList, "EmployeeId", "EmployeeValue", itemsTobeSelected);
```

enjoy...